# Use the path for a spreadsheet that is provided in another cell in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, function, path, reference

Good day,

I have two spreadsheets and I'm trying to get values from the second spreadsheet (Sheet.xlsx) to the main spreadsheet. This works perfectly by providing the whole path manually, but I want to get the path from another cell in the main sheet, like shown below:

[image]

This obviously doesn't work, because there is no such function. The aim is, to get the value from A1 from Sheet.xlsx to the main sheet in D2, whereas the path to Sheet.xlsx is provided in C2 of the main sheet (and this cell should be used for the function). What path it should produce:

[image]

Is this possible to do?

Comment: in D2: `=INDIRECT("'" & A2 & "[" & B2 & "]'Sheet1!A1")`

Comment: Thank you @TimWilliams, that's exactly what I needed! By applying this, I found out, that in my question I must've done a mistake in the second picture: the last apostrophe should e after "Sheet1", and not before. Then it works perfectly! You could post this as an answer, I'm sure people will find it useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm looping the solution provided by @TimWilliams, with a slight correction - the function that should be placed in D2 to solve the issue raised in the question, should be as follows:

```
=INDIRECT("'" & A2 & "[" & B2 & "]Sheet1'!A1")
```

[image]

**Note:** When referring to another workbook, like in this example, it will only work if you have both workbooks opened at the same time.